# Issues while trying to create phonegap app with rails

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, cordova

I am trying to create a sample app using `phonegap-rails` gem. I am getting an issue with the `phonegap_rails.yml` file.

This is my `Phonegap_Rails` file

```
phonegap_path:             '~/Development/phonegap-2.6.0'
package:                'com.example.Phonegap_Rails'
```

getting this error while following the mentioned steps in the repo

> rake aborted!
>   Psych::SyntaxError: (): did not find expected key while parsing a block mapping

Please help.

PS: If there's any better tutorial links of phonegap app with rails, It would be great.
Thanks.

Comment: Malformed Yaml? https://github.com/tenderlove/psych/issues/190

Comment: still open issue. :-/

Comment: Well, the issue is partly that it is reporting the wrong line number, that is still open. The real source of the problem is malformed YAML, though. Make sure everything is properly nested and indented. Use 2 spaces (not tabs) for indentation.

Comment: yeah did that but doesn't work.. know any tutorial for phonegap+rails for android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging by the [example file](https://github.com/joscas/phonegap-rails/blob/master/lib/generators/phonegap_rails/install/templates/config/phonegap_rails.yml), it looks like your YAML is malformed:

try making it exactly like:

```
phonegap_path: '~/Development/phonegap-2.6.0'
android:
  package: 'com.example.Phonegap_Rails'
```